# What's the probability of a certain event occurring when there are an infinite number of possibilities?

Tags: probability

Suppose that I am playing a game and I choose a random integer. As there are an infinite number of integers I can choose from, what is the probability that I choose the number 5?

I figured that the probability would be $$\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0$$ but the probability of choosing a 5 is not 0... there is still a possibility that 5 is chosen even though there are an infinite number of possibilities. How do I represent the probability?

Comment: In order to speak of choosing as a possibility, one should be able to meaningfully compare the number of ways of getting a 5 compared to every other possible outcome. But there's 1 way of getting a 5 compared to an infinite number of ways _not_ to get a 5. So if we insist on having _all_ integers as possibilities (as compared to a large but finite set) the probability of getting a 5 is nil.

Comment: Another statement which amounts to the same thing: If 5 had a small but nonzero probability $\epsilon>0$, then all things held equal every other integer would have that probability. But then the total probability of__something_ happening would be $\epsilon\times \infty> 1$, which doesn't make sense as a probability of anything at all!

Comment: I can't say that this way of thinking is necessarily correct, it's just what always goes through my mind When I see a question/problem like this. How do you pick a value when there isn't a bound to what you can pick? I'm always thinking I'd be stuck in limbo trying to pick something. Whether the reasoning is correct or not, it helps me see why the answer is what it is.

Comment: Why you are not surprised that interval unit length $[0,1]$  consists of points with length $0$. Event of probability 0 is not impossible event. It is "almost surely" impossible event. And event of probability 1 does not mean in general that the event almost happens. It happens "almost surely". For instance taking any number on $[0,1]$ has probability 1 to hit [$[0,1)$ and probability $0$ to get $1$. Nevertheless you can take $1$ with the same prob as any other number.

Comment: Is it possible that one assign any distribution function to this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of selecting a specific member from a countable infinite set of *equally weighted* discrete elements is *immeasurable*.   Although it may be certain that a member of the set is selected, it *almost surely* will not be that specified member.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to^+\infty} \Pr(X=k \mid X\sim{\cal U}\{-n, \ldots n\}) & = \lim_{n\to^+\infty} \frac 1 {2n+1} \times\operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{-n,\ldots n\}}(k)
\\ & = 0 \quad\text{ a.s.}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are many probability measures on the set of natural numbers.

However, there is no probability measure that assigns equal weight to all points. For if that weight is positive, we violate the fact that the sum of the probabilities over the sample space is $1$. And if that weight is $0$, then by countable additivity the weight of the sample space is $0$, not $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the game instructs the player to choose a random integer by repeatedly rolling a $6$-sided die until it shows a $6$, then adding up the previous rolls. There are infinitely many possibilities, but there are only finitely many ways to end up with a total of $5$. We need to sum the following probabilities:

$$p(111116) = 1/6^6$$
$$p([1112]6) = 4/6^5$$
$$p([122]6) = 3/6^4$$
$$p([113]6) = 3/6^4$$
$$p([23]6) = 2/6^3$$
$$p([14]6) = 2/6^3$$
$$p(56) = 1/6^2$$

Unless I've screwed up one of my calculations, the sum is

$$\frac{1}{6^6}+\frac{4}{6^5}+\frac{3}{6^4}+\frac{3}{6^4}+\frac{2}{6^3}+\frac{2}{6^3}+\frac{1}{6^2}=\frac{2401}{6^6}=0.05146\ldots$$

Of course, different rules will give you different probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As André Nicolas wrote in is answer, there is no uniform probability measure on a countable infinite set.

But in general, an event having probability 0 does not necessarily means that it cannot happen.
For example we can pick a number in the interval $[0,1]$ in a uniform probability. So the probability of us getting any specific number $a$ is 0, yet clearly any realization of a random variable with that probability will be some number.

If you want to learn more about probability measures over infinite sets, you should probably start with general measure theory.